# how to get the sessionscope attribute in html

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, servlet-filters

I am passing the session attribute in the servlet as follows

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("firstName","XYZ");
```

I have used this session attribute in other servlets .

I'm trying to get the session scope attribute in html page ( I dont want to change it to JSP)

```
<body onload="getName('<%= session.getAttribute(\"firstName\")%>');">
.....


<script type="text/javascript">
function getName(){
firstName= firstName;
}
....
</script>
```

But ');">  this part in the body tag is showed in the html page when it gets loaded and i'm not able to get the name from the session.

is there any that could be done with out changing it to jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
 <body onload="getName();">
.....


<script type="text/javascript">
function getName(){
 var firstName= '<%= session.getAttribute("firstName")%>';
 alert(firstName);
}
....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
<body onload="getName('<%= session.getAttribute("firstName")%>');">

<script type="text/javascript">
function getName(firstName){
//Here you can use the value of firstName as per your requirement.
alert(firstName);
}

 ....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use EL

```
<body onload="getName($sessionScope.firstName);">
```

Simplarly you can use

```
$sessionScope.firstName
```

whenever you require the firstName attribute which is stored in session.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstNameFromSession='${sessionScope.firstName}';
alert(firstNameFromSession);
```

then you could access the session attribute with the name firstName in Javascript